# Can I make systemd run the command in ExecStartPre during a restart? Should I?

Tags: systemd

My service is a game server, and I've added updating the server files as a command in `ExecStartPre`. I want this command to run also when I am restarting the service, but it seems that this command is ignored during a restart.

How can I make the service restart execute the commands in `ExecStartPre`?

This is my service config file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Game Server
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=none
WorkingDirectory=/home/someuser
ExecStartPre=/home/someuser/somegame update
ExecStart=/home/someuser/somegame start
ExecStop=/home/someuser/somegame stop
RemainAfterExit=false
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
SuccessExitStatus=1

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: `ExecStartPre` runs on restart.